# How to display a text message at the Center of the view when the List datasource is empty in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, empty-list

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display a message at the centre of the view when the list view (table view) is empty. What is the best way to achieve this in SwiftUI. Is checking for the data source count in "onAppear" and setting some sort of Bool value the correct approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            if landmarkData.count == 0 {
              VStack {
                Text("is empty")
              } else {
              List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                 LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply try an if else statement. If landmarkdata is nil or count = 0, show a text. Else show the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your message to have the same behavior as a list item, use `ScrollView` and `GeometryReader`.

Embed the condition state in the `Group`, so that the `NavigationView` is displayed in any case.

Don't forget to change the background color and ignore the safe area, for more resemblance to a list.

```swift
struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                if landmarkData.isEmpty {
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        ScrollView {
                            Text("Your message!")
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .padding()
                                .position(x: geometry.size.width/2, y: geometry.size.height/2)
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))
                } else {
                    List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                        LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use `@ViewBuilder` to provide an empty state view in the list, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62398882/10952522).