# Show a placeholder when a SwiftUI List is empty

Tags: swiftui, empty-list

When showing a List in a SwiftUI view, how do I specify placeholder content to show instead of the list if the list is empty?

Comment: A special case of this question, focusing in on a specific formatting requirement, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60897901/145173).

Comment: Duplicate of: [SwiftUI list empty state view/modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62398534/145173)